# Cloudinary Upload Widget - Apply general upload limit/ stop the upload process

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, limit, cloudinary

I have a question about Cloudinary jQuery Upload Widget.
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget

I use the max_files value "2" to limit the upload files in multiple mode, but it means "2 files per upload try" (= if user click Select... button again, he can upload more images).

I want to achieve the following:

- apply a general limit of uploaded images for the upload widget on a page load (example: 5)
- if the limit is exceeded, an alert should be displayed.

My code example is the following.
Look on the upload success function.
It seems it display the alert on the correct case, but the limit is not applied, 'cause that function is running after an upload success. But I want to stop the upload of files if the limit is exceeded.

```
    var uploaded_files_cnt = 0;
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var uploaded_files_cnt = 0;
        cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ 
                cloud_name: 'X', 
                upload_preset: 'Y', 
                max_files: 2,
                inline_container: '#inline_container'       
                }, 
            function(error, result) { 
                imageresults = result;
                for (i = 0; i < imageresults.length; i++) 
                {           
                            if (uploaded_files_cnt >= 5)
                            {
                                alert('No more images!');   
                                return false;
                            }
                            uploaded_files_cnt++;           
                }           

          });
    });
```

I check the widget's API events, but I don't find something useful...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're describing can be achieved by using jQuery from the callback function, for example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" 

type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<div class="uploader"><a href="#" id="upload_widget_opener" class="cloudinary-button">Upload</a></div>
$('#upload_widget_opener').cloudinary_upload_widget( 
{ cloud_name: 'XXXXX', 
upload_preset: 'XXXXX', 
max_files: '5', 
inline_container: '#inline_container'  
}, 
function(error, result) { 
    console.log(error, result) 
    $('.uploader').toggle(); // closes the widget. You can change it to an alarm
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) I understand your solution, but I need a way to show a friendly message to user and disable the use of widget, not just disappearing the widget. I need to just disable the widget from uploading more files. I add the following code on the callback function, but it is not working:        $("#inline_container *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
       $('.cloudinary_fileupload').attr("disabled","disabled");
       $('.button.select_file.select_single').attr("disabled","disabled");
       $('.button.select_file.select_multiple').attr("disabled","disabled");